# I only want to get the first 'firstPerson' parameter from the nested array

Tags: php

I only want to show the json_encode of this array parameter 'firstPerson'.

```
$someArray = [
    "firstPerson" => [
      "name"   => "Jonathan",
      "gender" => "male"
    ],
    "secondPerson" => [
      "name"   => "William",
      "gender" => "male"
    ],
    "thirdPerson" => [
      "name"   => "Allison",
      "gender" => "female"
    ]
  ];

  // Convert Array to JSON String
$someJSON = json_encode($someArray);
  echo $someJSON;
```

Comment: `$someJSON = json_encode($someArray["firstPerson"]);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the first element and then encode it to json like :

```
$someJSON = json_encode($someArray['firstPerson']);
echo $someJSON; 
// output :
// {"name":"Jonathan","gender":"male"}
```